# Can I allow addresses that get 'ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT' to be whitelisted on my sites

Tags: javascript, analytics, matomo, adblock

I'm getting some 'ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT' messages in my console relating to some analytics/tracking I have installed on my site, which seems to be coming from my overly enthusiastic adblocker. Unfortunately, I can't change the addresses that they are going to because it's built in to the analytics the 3rd party system is trying to use (Livestream/Matomo analytics, that kind of stuff) and obviously for this tracking I can't just ask every user to disable their adblocker, but is there a way of saying that on my site, requests that go to these addresses are safe and shouldn't be considered worthy of being blocked?

Comment: no - adblocker control is solely in the hands of the end user - your site has no say in it whatsoever

Comment: If there were a way to do this, *every* website would do it, and adblocking would lose all meaning.

Comment: @ChrisG, that's exactly what I was worried about, I figured that would be the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

That would completely defeat the point of browser plugins that block tracking services.

People don't want to be tracked or slow down web pages loading trackers.

You can't expect people to take a statement of "but my use of this third party tracking service you've blocked is completely benign and harmless and the third party isn't going to do anything evil with your data either" seriously, let along for tracking blocking plugins to provide you with an automated way of saying that to silently disable them.

Comment: Thanks, I figured that would be the case, if I can put something on my website to say X,Y, and Z are 'safe' what would stop someone doing the exact same thing for nefarious purposes on their website.